# Define your centroids in R

Tags: r, centroid

So I am using R to do some K-means clustering but the thing is that i already have the centroids values, and i want to input those values so that my data can be organised around those centroids. Is there a way to do that? For example I have the next set of centroids:

```
1.748792704, 2.269882797, 2.778176265, 3.390162239, 4.039893077, 4.595271061
```

Thanks

Comment: The centroids you are speaking of are the final ones? (The ones you want after the clustering is zone?)

Comment: Input the centroids into the `center` argument to the `kmeans` function.

Comment: yes,those are the final centroids, around them i want to centralise my data